# Is the test function topology a Mackey topology?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, topological-vector-spaces, duality

I am a physicist, and I have lately been thinking about distributions as they appear in quantum field theory. In the standard development of the theory of distributions, one considers the space $C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ of compactly supported smooth functions, and puts a topology on this space making it a topological vector space, where a net $\phi_{\alpha}$ converges to zero iff all $\phi_{\alpha}$ have support in a common compact set $K$ on which $\phi_{\alpha}$ and all its derivatives converge uniformly to zero. With this topology, sometimes called the canonical LF topology, the space of test functions is renamed $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ following the notation introduced by Schwartz.

There has been plenty said, on mathoverflow and elsewhere, about the intuitive motivation behind this choice of topology. From my perspective as a physicist and the applications I have in mind, none of these explanations is quite satisfactory. However, there is a standard result in the theory of distributions that I do find conceptually compelling: a linear map $\Lambda : \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d) \to \mathbb{C}$ is a distribution if and only if it can be written as a weak-* limit of smooth functions, i.e., if and only if there exists a sequence $f_j \in \mathbb{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f_j \phi \to \Lambda(\phi)$ for every $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d).$

I am interested in thinking about how one would reformulate the theory of distributions taking this theorem as the basic definition. In this framework, one would *define* a distribution as a linear functional on $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ obtained as a weak-* limit of smooth functions. In trying to understand this, I have read a bit about locally convex topologies consistent with a duality. As I understand, there is a family of locally convex topologies on $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ consistent with having the standard space of distributions as its continuous dual. In Mackey's theory, these locally convex topologies are classified in terms of a family of weak-* compact sets of the dual; one fixes this family, then uses its polars in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to construct a local subbase for a locally convex topology. For a general topological vector space $X$ with chosen dual space $X',$ the "Mackey topology" is the strongest topology for which the continuous dual is $X'$.

My question is: *is the canonical LF topology on $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ equal to the Mackey topology induced by the space of distributions?* I have convinced myself that the canonical LF topology is strictly stronger than the weakest topology on $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for which the continuous dual is the space of distributions, because I think I can construct a sequence of test functions that converges to zero when acted on by any distribution, but which does not converge to zero in the LF topology. [EDIT: As pointed out by P. P. Tuong in the comments, the previous sentence is incorrect; no such sequence exists.] But I'm totally lost as regards the other locally convex topologies on $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ consistent with having the space of distributions as its continuous dual, and it isn't clear to me where the canonical LF topology sits within this family.

Comment: 1. The statement in the first paragraph is true for sequences but not in the context of nets.  2. The answer to the title question is yes (see, for example, the monograph of Köthe).

Comment: It's interesting to know that the coarsest topology on $\mathcal C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ giving the space of distributions for continuous dual and the canonnical LF topology actually have the same convergent sequences and give them the same limits.

Comment: @terceira I'm surprised to hear that the first statement is not true for nets; do you know of a reference explaining net convergence in the LF topology? I will also look at the monograph of Köthe

Comment: @P.P.Tuong Can you recommend a source explaining this claim? I'm quite surprised to hear that, as I thought I had a counterexample.

Comment: @Jon You can find an explanation for this in Bourbaki's [*Topological Vector Spaces*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-61715-7), chap. IV, § 2, no. 5, example 4) and prop. 8.

Comment: Oh I see, of course --- this is the natural application of Banach-Steinhaus to the present setting. Thanks!

Comment: @jon.  Regarding nets, you can simply construct one (rather silly) net which at first runs through all points in the space (suitably ordered) and then becomes constant from a certain point on.

Comment: @terceira Two questions:
1) I don't understand what you mean. These are nets of smooth, compactly supported functions, not nets of points, so I don't understand your construction.
2) I have looked through the monograph of Köthe and I can't find any statement that the LF topology is a Mackey topology. Note that, as explained in the question, by "Mackey topology" I mean the strongest locally convex topology consistent with a duality, not just any polar topology consistent with a duality.

Comment: Hard for me to know what to say.  As regards to nets, you habe so much freedom.   So you can start with one which is all over the place (specifically, not in any component space), then settles down to a constant.  Any good text on lcs's will show that barrelled spaces (which the space of test functions is) have the Mackey topology.

Comment: @terceira Ahh, I see, OK, I was missing the connection barreled=>(initial = Mackey). If you post that as an answer I will accept it.